# Script criado no Pycharm fecha ao apertar a tecla "enter" dentro do terminal

Tags: python, script, pycharm

É o seguinte. Sou novo no meio da programação.
Uso o PyCharm para estudar python.
Quando tento executar um script criado no PyCharm pelo IDLE, logo após eu apertar a tecla "enter" a janela fecha. Os scripts criados no IDLE executam normalmente até o fim.
Por exemplo. Eu dou dois cliques no o script que eu criei no PyCharm, vai abrir aquela janela do terminal, a primeira linha do código é um input vamos supor. Logo após eu escrever algo e apertar o "enter", a janela ja fecha. Mas se eu pegar o mesmo código, salvar o script pelo IDLE, o programa funciona normalmente. Por que será que isso acontece?
Séra que é algum bug do próprio PyCharm? Sou um pouco leigo ainda, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

sem ver o teu código fica um pouco difícil te ajudar, mas acredito que o que está acontecendo é algo normal:

- o programa executa o código
- para pra receber uma informação
- realiza todos os passos seguinte e finaliza tão rápido (como obviamente tem de ser) que vc não vê o que está acontecendo.

Você consegue visualizar pelo PyCharm porque ele foi feito pra vc desenvolver qualquer programa, já o terminal não é exatamente uma interface gráfica ideal pra vc utilizar.

Se você quiser escrever um programa que tenha interação com o usuário, existem frameworks pra isso como o PyQt, Tkinter, wxPython, PySide... e vários outros.

Espero que isso te dê um norte, caso contrário, edita sua pergunta e deixa a gente entender melhor o que está passando na sua cabeça